# Detect space between second and third word and move words to next line

Tags: java, android

I have a list of names in an Adapter. When the name is being highlighted and if the name is too long (more than 2 words), I need to move the words after the gap of second word to next line in such a way that the words moved in new line maintain same space with the next name in Adapter.

The example is, consider the list of names in the list as -

> . **Alex**
>
> . Martin Kooper Well
>
> . Thomas

(As you see, when first name is highlighted, since it is less than 2 words, I dont need to anything)

Now,

> . Alex
>
> . **Martin Kooper**
>
> **Well**
>
> . Thomas

(As you see, when second name is highlighted, since it is more than 2 words, I need to put the third word `Well` in next line. It should maintain same spacing with next element Thomas in the list)

Comment: It would be great if you provide what is **Input** and what **output** you are expecting.

Comment: Edited in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    String name = "some person name".trim();
    if(name.indexOf(" ") != name.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
        int secondSpacePos = name.indexOf(" ", name.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        name = name.substring(0, secondSpacePos) + "\n " + name.substring(secondSpacePos);
    }
```

Comment: I used your code... the 'name' displays in 2 lines if it is more than 2 words. But why my tetxview is still displaying in 1 line. I am ussing tv.setText(name)

Comment: Have you given maxLines property for the textview in layout ?? If it is "1" then only single line will be displayed.

Comment: I have given this android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:lines="2"

Comment: remove android:singleLine="true"

Comment: Oh i need it actually. Initially when the names are shown they need to be shown in single line. Only when they are highlighted and if it is more than 2 words, then I should display in next line

Answer (score 0):

you can use Split() for this

```
String string = "android iPhone Windows";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```

Here you can check array size. if size/2 > 1 then you can add "\n" and add string to String buffer and then set to your listview textview

Hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on bases of white space and store it in array.

Do the following stuff

```
 String name = "Martin Kooper Well";
            String[] newname = name.split(" ");

            if (newname.length>2)
            name = newname[0] +" " +newname[1] + "\n" +newname[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do it in your view layout. Specify enough item view's height for a 2-line textview. When there is not enough horizontal space for the bold name ( or even a very large name ) the text will split automatically to use the second line. Specifiying a height you will have all items equal.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:lines="2"/>
```